# How to filter for "nothing found" search result page in wordpress' functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, scripting

In my functions.php I have a function that is adding scripts to the single post sites. Unfortunately it adds it also to the "Nothing Found" search result page and that's the reason why I get following notice:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...
```

My filter in functions.php is:

```
if( is_single($post->ID) ){
 ...//adding my scripts
}
```

I tried to add `&& !is_search()` into the if condition but that didn't help. So how could I prevent loading my script into the "Nothing Found" site?

**Edit:**

```
if(is_singular('post')){...}
```

was a working solution.
More infos on this site: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_search

Comment: Is it redirecting to home page?

Comment: No. I just figured out that if(is_singular('post')){...} is a working solution